# I renamed my desktop directory and now cannot open it right

Tags: windows, cmd, desktop

In my computer desktop is named "Área de Trabalho", but when I am creating a project in the CLI, it does not go well because of these special characters. So I renamed the directory to Desktop in cmd with ren "Área de Trabalho" Desktop, now I can find my files but only when opening file explorer, when I open desktop GUI it is totally blank, do you know how to update this desktop path?

Answer (score 0):

Open file explorer, then right-click on the desktop icon on your left side, where all the drives are listed, select properties, and a dialog box will be opened "Desktop properties" then select Location Tab, and you can update the path over there.

In quick summary
Open File Explorer - > Right-click on the desktop icon on the left side -> select properties -> Inside the desktop properties dialog choose the location tab & update the required path.

Thank you.